# P/Invoke Return void*

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I have a C function with the following signature:

```
int __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl test(void* p);
```

The function implementation is as following:

```
int i = 9;

int test(void* p)
{
    p = &i;
    return 0;
}
```

From a C# application, i want to return the value of the reference through the pointer to the C# application, so i did the following:

```
[DllImport(@"lib\test.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int test(out IntPtr p);

IntPtr p = IntPtr.Zero;

test(out p);
```

However, p does not have any value back.

Any help please!!

Comment: Your C code is wrong, it should be `int**`.  Always make C code work first before you try to pinvoke it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the value of the caller's pointer argument, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
int test(void** p)
{
    *p = &i;
    return 0;
}
```

calling from C# something like

```
[DllImport(@"lib\test.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern unsafe int test(IntPtr* p);

public unsafe void DotNetFunc()
{
    IntPtr p;
    test(&p);
```

If you don't like the use of `unsafe`, you could change your C function to return a pointer instead, returning `NULL` to indicate an error if necessary.

```
int* test()
{
    return &i;
}

[DllImport(@"lib\test.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr test();

IntPtr p = test();
if (p == IntPtr.Zero)
    // error
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need unsafe code. But you do need to fix the C code. Like so:

```
void test(int** p)
{
    *p = &i;
}
```

And the C# code is:

```
[DllImport("...", , CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void test(out IntPtr p);
```

Call it like this:

```
IntPtr p;
test(out p);
```

And read the value like this:

```
int i = Marshal.ReadInt32(p);
```

Or return the pointer as the function return value:

```
int* test(void)
{
    return &i;
}
```

And in C#:

```
[DllImport("...", , CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr test();
```

And I'm sure you can do the rest.

Comment: +1. Didn't realise you could use `out` to avoid use of `unsafe` here

Comment: @simonc Thanks. I think an `IntPtr` return value is better, but I just wanted to add this answer so that the asker knew that `unsafe` could be avoided. There are very few scenarios where `unsafe` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pointer of pointer

```
int test(void** p)
{
    *p = &i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no reference type in C